# User creates 3 albums with different images in php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql

How can I let users create 3 albums(they choose the album name), with different images? I'm not sure how to **organize a database** also when it comes to this particular problem.

Comment: Well, what's your best guess?

Comment: Well, I was thinking something like this. To create an "albums" table with fileds : Images_array(varchar), name(varchar), user_id(int) which would tell me who created an album?

Comment: Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you already tried yourself to do this? This is not a code writing or tutoring service. Questions should show **evidence of research and attempts to solve the problem yourself**, a clear outline of your specific coding-related issue, and any relevant code, so we can help.

Comment: Of course I've tried to do it myself first, then tried to find a solution on Stack, and finally I asked a question, because I couldn't find anywhere how to properly think when approaching this specific problem. Sorry, I kneo that my question was too short, I just wanted to know how to approach the problem, not to find someone to do all the work for me of course.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a table of users, a table of albums, and a table of images.

The albums table might have columns for the id and name of the album, and the id of the user who created it.

The images table might simply store image ids as well as filepaths and meta data for images.

Then you might have another table which says which image belongs to which album - so a column for the album id and a column for the image id. This structure allows for the possibility that the same image might belong in more than one album.

The business logic (e.g. the limit on the number of albums a user can create) would typically be handled in application code. But you could handle it with a trigger, or even within the INSERT query for the album itself.

What you DEFINITELY wouldn't have is an 'array' of anything!

Comment: Wow, that makes so much sense. Why didn't I think of that since it's really simple solution. I guess it's my lack of experience in programming. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You will need two tables aside from your user table.

1. Album
2. Album_Images

This way you can create a [relational database](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-4PuIaEVaiQ)

The album will have

```
|--album_id--|--user_id--|--album_name--|
```

The Album_Images table will have:

```
|--image_id--|--album_id--|--image_file_name--|--image_location--|
```

This way you can find an album based on the image or the image based on the album.

```
SELECT * FROM album_images WHERE album_id=325
```